# Genymotion communicate with socket in different local subnet

Tags: java, android, sockets, virtualbox, genymotion

I have a virtual machine hosting a server located at 192.168.18. This server is listening on port 20000 for a connection from my Android application. I am doing this locally for testing purposes.

The Genymotion virtual machine is located at 192.168.57.1, and it does not appear to be able to communicate with the other server.

Is there a way to change Genymotion so that it will operate in the 192.168.1/24 subnet, or a way to get them to communicate properly?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily achieve this. You need to ask your Genymotion device to have a Bridged network connection instead of a NAT.

- Open VirtualBox
- Select the device you want to see on your local network
- Click on settings
- Open the Network tab and the Adapter 2
- Then switch from NAT to Bridged Adapter
- Start your Genymotion device

After that, your local DHCP will handle this new device and give it a local IP. You will be able then to reach you local network from it.

Note: This should be handled very soon directly from Genymotion soft, no need to open VirtualBox for this settings.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Now a different unrelated problem that I am having is that my socket is failing to connect to the Virtual Machine hosting my server at 192.168.1.18. My Genymotion VM is now hosted at 192.168.1.19. The application is stuck at loading until eventually the TCP connection times out. Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Try first to ping your server from the device (using adb shell). If it succeed I would suggest to check how you implemented the requests.